# How to pass a dynamic image path to a React card as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, browser

I'm trying to pass an image path that is loaded from a database to a React card. I can't do an import (at least it hasn't worked) and I've tried to add require(props.avatar) with no luck. Here's the code and I know the path is hard coded, I haven't got to the database part yet, but this should still work somehow...

App.js looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container comment main-list">
        <HeaderCard></HeaderCard>
        <SearchBar></SearchBar>
        <MainCard className="main">
          <MainDetail
            Name="Baby Buntings!"
            Date="11/12/20"
            text="What up!"
            **avatar="../images/benefit.jpg"**
            Price="$20.00"
          />
        </MainCard>
        <MainCard>
        .
        . (more data)
        .
```

MainDetail.js looks like this:

```
const MainDetail = props => {
  console.log(props.avatar);
  return (
    <div className="comment main-time-place">
      <a href="/">
        **<img className="main-image" alt="benefit" src={props.avatar} />**
      </a>
      <div className="content">
        <a href="/" className="author">
          Featuring: {props.Name}
          
        </a>
        <div className="metadata">
          <span className="date cardtext">Date: {props.Date}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="text cardtext">{props.text}</div>
        <div className="price cardtext">Price: {props.Price}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainDetail;
```

This code has this:
src={props.avatar}

but I've also tried
src={require(props.avatar)}

If I do an import with a hard coded path, it works, but I can't do that...

This seems like it should be simple to do. The images are uploaded by users on another page so I won't know what they are in advance so I can't import them. (Or can I???).

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When you import an image it is included in your deploy by whatever bundler you are using, as uploads by users aren't a static part of your solution you don't need to import them. You just need to know where the uploaded images will be served from, either by storing or calculating the path. So if your user uploads an image that is processed and then served at `www.yoursite.com/uploads/image1.jpg` then just using the string `/uploads/image1.jpg` in the src prop should be enough as this will be handled by the browser as it does for all other non-react pages serving images.

Comment: @JacobSmit: Thanks for the reply. My thought is there should be a way to make this work on my local during development. The console.log proves the prop is being passed in correctly, it has the correct relative path, but no image? Is there a way to show an image during development??? "My site" is running in react dev mode. I'm no where near deployment at this point.

Comment: What is handling the upload of the image on the server side, or is this not yet implemented and you are trying to test dynamically loading the images using test files and a static path?

Comment: @jacob Smit: YES! When I start to develop a page I hard code simple data before I save stuff to a database. My thought is if it can't find the image based on the path it doesn't matter where the data comes from. I'm blocked right now because the image won't show.  Ultimately the path will be retrieved as data saved on another page (which currently doesn't exist)